# How to nest object in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

In Knockout.js, what is the best way to nest object inside of an an array?

I am trying to have an observable that is sorted by a group of courses title and inside there would be different course offered to a student with the same group property ( course code).

This is my snippet

```js
function course(_id, _code, _title, _campus) {
    var self = this;
    this.id = ko.observable(_id);
    this.courseCode = ko.observable(_code);
    this.courseTitle = ko.observable(_title);
    this.coursecampus = ko.observable(_campus);
}

function gpCourseProperties(_code, _isHidden) {
    var self = this;
    this.gpCode = ko.observable(_code);
    this.hide = ko.observable(_isHidden);
    this.courses = ko.observableArray();

    this.addCourse = function (_id, _courseCode, _courseTitle, _courseCampus) {
        self.courses.push(new course(_id, _courseCode, _courseTitle, _courseCampus));
    }

    this.switchMutated = function (code) {
        self.hide(!self.hide());
    };
    this.switchText = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.hide() == true) {
            return '+'
        }
        return '-';
    }, this);
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.gpCourseProp = ko.observableArray();

self.gpCourseProp.push(new gpCourseProperties("MATH1030", true));
self.gpCourseProp.push(new gpCourseProperties("MATH1006", true));
self.gpCourseProp.push(new gpCourseProperties("MATH1046", true));

    for (i = 0; i < self.gpCourseProp().length; i++) {
    if (self.gpCourseProp()[i].gpCode == "MATH1030") {
        self.gpCourseProp()[i].addCourse(new course("1", "MATH1030", "Calculus", "City1"));
        self.gpCourseProp()[i].addCourse(new course("2", "MATH1030", "Calculus", "City2"));
        self.gpCourseProp()[i].addCourse(new course("3", "MATH1030", "Calculus", "City3"));
    }
    if (self.gpCourseProp()[i].gpCode == "MATH1006") {
        self.gpCourseProp()[i].addCourse(new course("4", "MATH1006", "Linear algebra", "City1"));
        self.gpCourseProp()[i].addCourse(new course("6", "MATH1006", "Linear algebra", "City2"));
    }
    if (self.gpCourseProp()[i].gpCode == "MATH1046") {
        self.gpCourseProp()[i].addCourse(new course("5", "MATH1046", "Discrete Math", "City1"));
        self.gpCourseProp()[i].addCourse(new course("7", "MATH1046", "Discrete Math", "City2"));
    }
    }
}

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
    tr.mutated {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Course Code</th>
            <th>Course Title</th>
            <th>Course Campus</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: gpCourseProp">
        <tr class="table-dark">
            <td></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data.gpCode"></span></td>
            <td><span></span></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ko foreach: $data.courses -->
        <tr data-bind="css: { mutated: $parent.mutated.hide() == true }">
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data.id"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data.courseCode"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data.courseTitle"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data.coursecampus"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The issue i have is trying to add courses to the gpCourseProperties.

Comment: *'I have jsfiddle but I have some issues. Here the jsfiddle."* Please do your runnable example **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issues are:

- When you initialize your data, you only `push` the arguments for `gpCourseProperties` to the observable array. You need to construct the viewmodel using `new`.
- When you create the `course` content for your `courseProperties`, you check `gpCode === "Some string"`. Since `gpCode` is `observable`, you need to extract its value using `()` for this to ever be true.

Here's an updated version with the minimum changes required to make it work. (note, I removed the CSS that hid some of the rows for debug purposes).

The fixes are marked in the comments.

```js
function course(_id, _code, _title, _campus) {
    var self = this;
    this.id = ko.observable(_id);
    this.courseCode = ko.observable(_code);
    this.courseTitle = ko.observable(_title);
    this.coursecampus = ko.observable(_campus);
}

function gpCourseProperties(_code, _isHidden) {
    var self = this;
    this.gpCode = ko.observable(_code);
    this.hide = ko.observable(_isHidden);
    this.courses = ko.observableArray();

    this.addCourse = function (_id, _courseCode, _courseTitle, _courseCampus) {
        self.courses.push(new course(_id, _courseCode, _courseTitle, _courseCampus));
    }

    this.switchMutated = function (code) {
        self.hide(!self.hide());
    };
    this.switchText = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.hide() == true) {
            return '+'
        }
        return '-';
    }, this);
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.gpCourseProp = ko.observableArray();

    // Fix 1:
    //                     vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv                v
    self.gpCourseProp.push(new gpCourseProperties("MATH1030", true));
    self.gpCourseProp.push(new gpCourseProperties("MATH1006", true));
    self.gpCourseProp.push(new gpCourseProperties("MATH1046", true));

    for (i = 0; i < self.gpCourseProp().length; i++) {
        // Fix 2:
        //                               vv
        if (self.gpCourseProp()[i].gpCode() == "MATH1030") {
            self.gpCourseProp()[i].addCourse("1", "MATH1030", "Calculus", "City1");
            self.gpCourseProp()[i].addCourse("2", "MATH1030", "Calculus", "City2");
            self.gpCourseProp()[i].addCourse("3", "MATH1030", "Calculus", "City3");
        }
        if (self.gpCourseProp()[i].gpCode() == "MATH1006") {
            self.gpCourseProp()[i].addCourse("4", "MATH1006", "Linear algebra", "City1");
            self.gpCourseProp()[i].addCourse("6", "MATH1006", "Linear algebra", "City2");
        }
        if (self.gpCourseProp()[i].gpCode() == "MATH1046") {
            self.gpCourseProp()[i].addCourse("5", "MATH1046", "Discrete Math", "City1");
            self.gpCourseProp()[i].addCourse("7", "MATH1046", "Discrete Math", "City2");
        }
    }
}

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Course Code</th>
            <th>Course Title</th>
            <th>Course Campus</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: gpCourseProp">
        <tr class="table-dark">
            <td></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: gpCode"></span></td>
            <td><span></span></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ko foreach: courses -->
        <tr data-bind="css: { mutated: $parent.hide() == true }">
            <td><span data-bind="text: id"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: courseCode"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: courseTitle"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: coursecampus"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```